# Can I stop battery charging at say 80% and switch to AC?

Tags: power-management, battery

While I was looking for a battery management utility for my Dell E5420, I came to read this post - [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity) . Sofar, I haven't found one that relates to my laptop.

So, I wonder now if any battery manager utility can be found for my laptop specified above. I would be happy if someone could point me if such utility is available under Ubuntu 12.04 that can stop charging a battery at a certain percentage and to ONLY use A/C mode. Again, to start using battery mode when the A/C is off or when the battery level reaches at certain level.

Thanks for all your help.

Elim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)

Comment: Specifically https://askubuntu.com/a/1351481/7808

Answer (score 2):

It will not be possible because the laptop will require hardware support as well, assuming built into the BIOS. The software is mearley showing the charge percentage and rate, but power is flowing to the battery either way unless otherwise told by hardware. Also, if you shut your PC off, how does it know to stop charging without direction of a software utility. Make sense? I was looking for something similar for my Dell Studio, but it is not possible unless built into the motherboard from the manufacturer. Hopefully Dell catches on.