# How do I limit battery charging to 80% on Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, power-management, battery, battery-charging-threshold

I'm using a Dell XPS 13 7390 and am wondering if this is possible. I can do this in Windows but the Dell power management app doesn't seem to be available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The title is not always available to all users especially if they use a phone to read. Please include the question in the question body. You might try wine to run it I do not know if it supports it.

Comment: Look in the BIOS setting. There you can set that.

Comment: Did you find anything posted useful? It is good for the community that you provide feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I stop battery charging at say 80% and switch to AC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156114/can-i-stop-battery-charging-at-say-80-and-switch-to-ac)

Comment: Specifically https://askubuntu.com/a/1351481/7808

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [Dell Command Configure](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-ar/000178000/dell-command-configure).

After installing, run

```
$ sudo cctk --PrimaryBattChargeCfg=Custom:<low>-<high>
```

and adapt the low/high thresholds.

Comment: In case someone like me is looking for `cctk`, try `/opt/dell/dcc/cctk`