# Battery Life Extender for Linux

Tags: 12.10, battery, lenovo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)

I have Lenovo notebook. There is an utility for Windows called kind of Battery Extender which extends battery life because it doesn't allow the battery be charged more than 50%. It's developed by Lenovo.

Since there is no  that official utility for Ubuntu on Lenovo web site, do you know any one which is similar to it?

Comment: The actual level cited by Lenovo is 80% and there's actually some basis for the assertion http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries . Apparently there is a way to get this working, please see this previous question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity

Comment: @fabricator4, It doesn't work for me for some reason. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Alex, did you manage to get this working with the updated instruction on the other question?  It seems that you were having trouble creating the required file due to a permissions problem.