# Is there a Dell Longevity option in Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, battery, xps

Dell XPS has the following option in Windows 8: I assume it's a hardware switch that is set somehow, so does it stick when rebooting to Ubuntu? Is there a way to check or switch this option from Linux?

I assume there's a driver somewhere since Dell makes the XPS 13, a Linux-preinstalled version of the XPS.

[image: Dell Battery Longevity Mode]

Comment: Think this might help not sure though http://askubuntu.com/a/72570/263677

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS? I can set this in the BIOS of my XPS 15 9530.

Comment: @Starfall I don't remember seeing that as an option - what is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
Use [DELL Command | Configure](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000178000/dell-command-configure?lang=en#:%7E:text=Windows%20download-,Linux%20downloads,-Ubuntu%20Desktop%2018.04)

---

**This answer is no longer relavent**

Dell longevity feature is **only usable on Windows OS via driver**.

**Dell haven`t developed any program** to support that feature on Linux, also there are **no third party drivers** for that.

Comment: That's what I guessed, but... what's your source for this?

Comment: I asked a question at Dell Support! You can try it at Dell helpline number.

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers have mentioned, this is not a hardware switch, but instead a software function. There is a kernel module available (tp-smapi-dkms), but it only works for Lenovo ThinkPads.

Enabling this function on your Dell laptop would require you or the vendor to write and implement a kernel module for your laptop model, the same way as they wrote the software for Windows.

Right now, your best bet is to unplug the battery manually when it's reached 80%. If you have some coding skills, you can use acpitool and notify-send to write an script to let you know when the battery has reached its 80%. `acpitool -B` will display information about your battery, from where you can grep some information.

tl;dr: No, you cannot do it at this point, your vendor would need to write the software as it's not a hardware switch.

Comment: So Dell doesn't write a driver for this, not even for the XPS 13 Ubuntu edition?

Comment: That's correct - even though they have Ubuntu preinstalled in some machines they don't offer the kernel module. I think you may try complaining with them, but as they're a company maybe developing that specific kernel module doesn't fit their interests/roadmap.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool from dell
https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln311302/dell-command-configure?lang=en

which is probably doing what you want

https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/de/de/debsdt1/command-configure-v3.3/dellcommandconfigure-cli-3.3/--peakshiftbatterythreshold?guid=guid-82cdbc77-c6ed-4590-ac36-281862cf0593&lang=en-us

Comment: Does that work in English, and does that work in Linux? The command starts with `C:` in that page.

Comment: Yep this tool is both for linux and windows. Jus run the command from /opt/dell/dcc/cctk.  I suppose Dell have it in English too. For some reason, they keep switching me to German, probably geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this link and it looks like it's working..
No errors. I'll keep you updated if it does stop at 80%
https://github.com/glynhudson/dell-charge-limit

Comment: How did you do this since Dell Command | Configure  is only available as a download for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

no, it is not a hardware swtich. it is a software function. you can even set the same thing to happen in ubuntu. look at the link below for clarification.

[How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember any BIOS setting for this, and that link is for Lenovo battery limit system.

Comment: it is not a bios function. changing the charge limit is a function of kernel. that is what i wanted to show that charging limit is a function of kernel(the commands are self-explanatory). i have the same setting on my fujitsu laptop. so you can enable it on any laptop.

Comment: @aveemashfaq The linked question is specifically for Lenovo and does not address the laptop that I have (Dell Inspiron). Can you care explain what steps you took on the fujitsu laptop to stop charging the battery at 80%?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, on the Dell XPS 15 (model 9550), this option seems to work in linux *if you enable in the BIOS*. That is, the XPS 15 provides both an Windows tool (Dell Command Power Manager, or something like that) and BIOS options to set the battery change behavior.

If you set the BIOS options, they seem to work in Ubuntu. That is, I've set it to 90% max change, and the change state in Ubuntu goes up to 89% and stays there.

There are some inconsistencies though - sometimes it breaks through the 89% barrier and goes up to 100%. I haven't figured that out yet.