# Battery Threshhold

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04, which is really nice but my battery is not charging past 59%. I recall tinkering with Lenovo battery management on Windows to reserve the life span but I wiped Windows so I can't get to the settings.

I followed this post [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity) and did the following by installing `tp smapi` but it's in a different directory than the one posted, it's under `usr/src` and I see the file along with folders there.

What are the next steps to change the charge rate to 100% and keeping those settings permanent?

Comment: I reinstalled windows and downloaded battery management software which fixed the problem. I still would like to adjust my current threshold settings.