# how to disable charging in ubuntu when battery level is above 80 percent?

Tags: 14.04, power-management, lenovo, battery, tp-smapi

I tried various tutorials to stop charging laptop battery but it is not working on my Lenovo laptop. I tried following commands:

```
 sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms  
 sudo modprobe tp_smapi
```

gives error :

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tp_smapi': No such device
```

my system :
  Ubuntu 14.04
  Lenovo b40-70

Comment: You can refer the url to limit the battery level: http://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be use a guild which write for a Thinkpad. But you should know that **tp_smapi is for real Thinkpads only**.

Not for all Lenovo. And not even all Thinkpads are supported. See [this page on Thinkwiki.org](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi) which models are supported. It doesn't mention yours there.

From the same [Thinkwiki.org page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi):

The the new Lenovo series have firmware that is completely different from other ThinkPad models. Neither tp_smapi nor thinkpad-acpi support these models.

These are consumer-grade notebooks, from the original Lenovo line. The supported Thinkpads are more of the original IBM-line of machines with a completely different design in hardware. The component that's key here is the embedded hardware controller for this unique power controlling feature. As far as I know, only the business-line of Thinkpads still feature this today.

Short history: Lenovo bought IBM's Thinkpad line of machines in 2005, but even till today the machines between the Thinkpad T/X/W series can't be compared to the consumer-grade machines in terms of compatibility (and quality).

Bottom line: you can't do this on your device.