# Battery will not charge past 59%. I have no access to Windows or lenovo softwares anymore

Tags: laptop, power-management, lenovo, battery

I have an Ideapad Touch u430 that came with **AOE licence**. As it was recommanded, I used the Energy Manager to enable the Economy mode (I don't remember the exact name) that **makes your battery stop charging at 59%** for a long battery life. It's a Lenovo proprietary software.
I installed Ubuntu and deleted windows for good. I didn't disable the Economy mode before making the switch.
Ubuntu is working fine, but the battery still stops charging at 59%. It must be something in the bios. But I cannot find it. 
Since the Lenovo Energy Manager is a proprietary software (a blotware that comes with the computer), I cannot study its code or show it to more experienced developers to reverse this very annoying action.
I checked every available solution, they all involve going back to win8/Energy Manager. I cannot go back to Windows, I have no licence now. Even if I install it again, there is no chance to get the Lenovo softwares back.

Comment: I'd try to go back to windows (perhaps with a someone elses licence, you'll only use it for a few minutes anyway), and download the software from http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds031269

Comment: Can I get it done using windows in a virtual machine ?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Have you tried Fred Schoen solution from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is possibly running it from a live session of msdos or from a windows installation or rescue disk.

Comment: also, https://askubuntu.com/a/562525/167115

Comment: @mchid That wouldn't work because a piece of software like this would require direct hardware access AFAIK as per [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8021e00ae87d4fbfb607739af82bdb621b9d9366).

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness yes the OP already tried wine and it didn't work, however I believe the package `tp-smapi-dkms` provides the capability to interact with the same settings and the windows software may not actually be needed see https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity