# Restoring Old Battery Settings

Tags: 20.04, dell, battery

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312186/battery-thresholds-in-ubuntu-dell/1314670?noredirect=1#comment2238054_1314670), I asked on how to set battery thresholds in Ubuntu 20.04. I would now like to undo this, but I am not sure on how to do it. I followed the bountied answer in the thread. Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation that Sasuke linked to](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/command-configure_reference-guide_en-us.pdf), you can set the `PrimaryBattChargeCfg` value back to standard with something like this:

```
$ sudo ./cctk --PrimaryBattChargeCfg=Standard
```

If you would rather use Dell's adaptive algorithm, which I believe is the default, then you would do something like this:

```
$ sudo ./cctk --PrimaryBattChargeCfg=Adaptive
```

From what I can tell, this should also be possible from the BIOS itself

Comment: For me, this didn't work out of the terminal, but I could change the settings from the BIOS and I now changed it to adaptive. :)