# How do I configure my Asus laptop to switch to AC Power on reaching a threshold charge on Battery?

Tags: 20.04, power-management, asus, battery

I have a ASUS laptop ->  Asus TUF A15 . I want to set the laptop to use AC source for power once it charges to a threshold of 70%. In Windows I have the option to do this.

Upon a google search I found an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006778/set-battery-thresholds-on-ubuntu-asus) .
Go I go to the location --> /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold --> Tried to edit and save it by setting it to 70. But it doesn't work.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean "I have the file and can edit it, but the battery charges beyond 70%" or do you mean "The file exists, but I cannot edit it" or do you mean "The file does not exist at all"? The contents of the `/sys/class/power_supply` directory can vary from machine to machine — even if using the same model — due to BIOS settings and/or battery manufacturers ...

Comment: I edited the file . But  when I save it, I get the following error : 

`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1$ sudo gedit charge_control_end_threshold 

(gedit:75368): Tepl-WARNING **: 10:30:13.061: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.`

Comment: Including error messages when asking for technical help will usually make it *easier* for others to offer assistance. Fortunately, the warning that you're seeing here is a non-issue. Generally, it's best to not use `sudo` with Gnome applications but, instead, the `admin://` schema. For example: `gedit admin:///sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold`. Either way, `BAT0` is what you reported in the question, `BAT1` is in your comment. Inconsistencies make things harder to solve. Please update your question to include the directory listing for `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1` 

Comment: Nowhere it say's that you have  to edit that file ... just echo the value into it. /sys is not a real filesystem, but an interface to see and set parameters in the kernel. But what is wrong with the defaults ? Doesn't your ASUS use AC when connected ?

Comment: My bad , thank you for informing me about these. Haven't heard of admin:// before.
I'll try the echo method and report back

Comment: Yep , I tried to echo it through terminal and it works. I did not notice that "BAT0" was different from whats in my system "BAT1" . I had copy pasted previously from the answer .
It now works. Thank you.

Also , I would like to learn what exactly does "echo" do ? Does it pass values to the config in this case?