# Limit charging threshold in ASUS laptop in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, asus, battery-charging-threshold

I'm currently using a dual-booted ASUS laptop (Windows and ubuntu). In windows, Asus has a feature to limit the charging threshold up to 60%. But when I log into ubuntu it starts to charge up to 100%. Is there any way to limit the charging threshold in ubuntu?

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Duplicate of: [Set battery thresholds on Ubuntu (ASUS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006778/set-battery-thresholds-on-ubuntu-asus) (based on OP's answer below)

Answer (score 0):

I could find out this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1230442/1340291

which helped me to solve my problem.