# "Operation not permitted" when trying to `modprobe xpad`

Tags: kernel, input-devices, xbox-one

I'm trying to use a new PDP Xbox One controller ("Crimson Red"). As is, my Ubuntu 18.10 system doesn't seem to recognize it; its power light doesn't even turn on. Using some hints posted [here](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/pdp-wired-controller-blue-camo-working-in-linux/131621), I got a copy of `xpad.c` for my kernel (4.18.0), edited `xpad.c` to add some lines for my controller's ID (0e6f:02c6), and [compiled and installed the module](https://github.com/brianguertin/xpad/blob/master/README.md). However, `sudo modprobe xpad` yields `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'xpad': Operation not permitted`. What gives? The output of `sudo modprobe -vvv xpad` is:

```
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:364 kmod_set_log_fn() custom logging function 0x5605fa960ee0 registered
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.dep.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.alias.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.symbols.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-index.c:755 index_mm_open() file=/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/modules.builtin.bin
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:556 kmod_module_new_from_lookup() input alias=xpad, normalized=xpad
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:562 kmod_module_new_from_lookup() lookup modules.dep xpad
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:574 kmod_search_moddep() use mmaped index 'modules.dep' modname=xpad
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:402 kmod_pool_get_module() get module name='xpad' found=(nil)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:410 kmod_pool_add_module() add 0x5605fc28bff0 key='xpad'
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:402 kmod_pool_get_module() get module name='ff_memless' found=(nil)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:402 kmod_pool_get_module() get module name='ff_memless' found=(nil)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:410 kmod_pool_add_module() add 0x5605fc28c100 key='ff_memless'
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:196 kmod_module_parse_depline() add dep: /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/input/ff-memless.ko
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:202 kmod_module_parse_depline() 1 dependencies for xpad
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:583 kmod_module_new_from_lookup() lookup xpad=0, list=0x5605fc28bc40
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:501 lookup_builtin_file() use mmaped index 'modules.builtin' modname=xpad
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1750 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/xpad/initstate': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1760 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/xpad': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_pcsp mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=cx88_alsa mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_atiixp_modem mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_intel8x0m mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_via82xx_modem mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=bt87x mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=cx88_alsa mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=saa7134_alsa mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_atiixp_modem mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_intel8x0m mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_via82xx_modem mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_caiaq mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_ua101 mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_us122l mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_usx2y mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_cmipci mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_pcsp mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=bonding mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=dummy mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=vmwgfx mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=vt mod->name=ff_memless mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:501 lookup_builtin_file() use mmaped index 'modules.builtin' modname=ff_memless
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1306 kmod_module_probe_insert_module() Ignoring module 'ff_memless': already loaded
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_pcsp mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=cx88_alsa mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_atiixp_modem mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_intel8x0m mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_via82xx_modem mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=bt87x mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=cx88_alsa mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=saa7134_alsa mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_atiixp_modem mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_intel8x0m mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_via82xx_modem mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_caiaq mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_ua101 mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_us122l mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_usx2y mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_cmipci mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_pcsp mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=snd_usb_audio mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=bonding mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=dummy mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=vmwgfx mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1393 kmod_module_get_options() modname=vt mod->name=xpad mod->alias=(null)
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1750 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/xpad/initstate': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1760 kmod_module_get_initstate() could not open '/sys/module/xpad': No such file or directory
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:744 kmod_module_get_path() name='xpad' path='/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.ko'
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:744 kmod_module_get_path() name='xpad' path='/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.ko'
insmod /lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.ko 
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:744 kmod_module_get_path() name='xpad' path='/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.ko'
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:886 kmod_module_insert_module() Failed to insert module '/lib/modules/4.18.0-13-generic/kernel/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.ko': Operation not permitted
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'xpad': Operation not permitted
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:468 kmod_module_unref() kmod_module 0x5605fc28bff0 released
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:418 kmod_pool_del_module() del 0x5605fc28bff0 key='xpad'
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:468 kmod_module_unref() kmod_module 0x5605fc28c100 released
modprobe: DEBUG: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:418 kmod_pool_del_module() del 0x5605fc28c100 key='ff_memless'
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:331 kmod_unref() context 0x5605fc284460 released
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Predictably, it was some dumb Secure Boot thing. Once I signed the module with

```
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n xpad)
```

I could `modprobe` it without issues, and the controller works well.

The files `MOK.priv` and `MOK.der` are Secure Boot keys, which I'd previously created using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/768310) to get VirtualBox working.

Comment: You said you extracted MOK.priv and MOK.der using a different answer. Can you give more details, please? Specifically, I am confused by your term "extractes" when the linked article creates new keys.

Comment: @timkay It's been some time since I did this, but I'm pretty sure I followed the steps in the linked answer. It looks like when I wrote this answer, I was confused and thought I'd decrypted preexisting keys instead of making new ones. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. 
you may want to add a line 
```
cd /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/
```

Comment: This will work on Ubuntu without generating custom keys, but you have to enter `/var/lib/shim-signed/mok` directory as Jobin pointed out, and then potentially run `mokutil --import MOK.der` inside of it, as in my case the key wasn't imported into MOK! Then reboot, confirm you want to import the key, and after booting you will be able to modprobe the module finally. Also Ubuntu nowadays uses sha512 rather than sha256. Note that all the dependent modules need to be signed too! (can be with different key ofc) -- check deps with modinfo

Answer (score 18):

if you are facing this error
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Operation not permitted

The solution is to disabled the Secure Boot.
Firstly check if SecureBoot is enabled on Ubuntu.

Install mokutil 
 "sudo apt-get install mokutil"

and check the status of SecureBoot
"mokutil --sb-state"

In case it is enabled run command
"sudo mokutil --disable-validation"

Now enter a temporary password between 8 to 16 digits. We will use this password later. Enter the same password again to confirm. Once it’s done reboot the system and press any key when you see the blue screen (MOK management). Select Change Secure Boot state.
Enter the password you had selected before and press Enter.
Select Yes to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed.
Press Enter key to finish the whole procedure.

Comment: My current kernel (5.3.0) has native support for this controller, so this is no longer an issue, but it appeared that I needed Secure Boot on in order to run Windows.