# Dell XPS Plus 9320 webcam not detected in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dell, webcam, xps

I have got a brand new Dell XPS Plus 9320. It came with Windows 11 but I installed Linux on it (Ubuntu 22.04).

So far, I have made everything work except the webcam.

The webcam is not detected at all.

I have double-checked it is enabled in the UEFI menu.

I have tried disabling it, rebooting and enabling it again.

`lsusb` does not show anything camera. There is no `/dev/videoX` device in the system.

I have asked Dell's support and they told me to install Windows to diagnose the problem (which I will not do).

Any suggestions on how to research further?

Thanks.

EDIT: here is the output of `lsusb`

```
→ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:63bc Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Pop!_OS is off-topic here.

Comment: ok, but I have the same problem on 22.04. I am going to rephrase the description then.

Comment: I have the same problem on a model shipped with Ubuntu 20.04 and immediately upgraded to 22.04. Everything seemed to work fine on 20.04 but now I cannot detect webcam, fingerprint reader and some other device I'm not sure what it was but I noticed it disappeared (looking in the "additional drivers" section of the software and updates settings.

Comment: @Earendil, I managed to get the fingerprint working with: ```apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd pam-auth-update```

Comment: The camera is also not working in fedora 36 by default. The fingerprint reader does work without any configuration though.

Comment: I had to factory-reset the computer to the OS it shipped with (Ubuntu 20.04) now everything works just fine, I think I will wait for the release of the firmware before upgrading again

Comment: @Earendil, do you have a copy of the ISO? Or can you make a recovery of the rescue partition? For most of us, when we try to download the image from the Dell website, it will not hand it over.

Comment: @KevinBBurns I have a 4.1 GB iso of the recovery but I don't really know how to properly share it given its size and that I'm not sure how nice is Dell about public sharing it

Comment: @Earendil, it's FOSS, so Dell can't say or do anything about it, the fact that they are making people jump through hoops after spending almost $3k on a laptop is insane. You can either make a torrent of it and see it for a while, which is preferred method to share unbutu iso's, or you can upload it to rapidshare and post a link. Might be better to post the link on Reddit, pretty sure Stack will filter it out.

Comment: @KevinBBurns
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:626de4fe7a9d1da24d32e25dfd84f0306fc99051&dn=ubuntu-20.04-amd64-dell%5FX00.iso

Answer (score 8):

Check out this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1955383

I got my webcam working, on a Dell Precision 5470 but the bug is for xps 9320, by first adding this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
```

Then install this package

```
sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0
```

After a reboot the webcam should work in a browser. Note that it won't work in cheese: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1978757

Comment: I have managed to get the camera appearing by installing `libcamhal-ipu6ep0`.

It appears in `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` and in Google Meet.

But Google Meet never shows the image. If I select "Intel MIPI camera" it says "Camera is starting" for a while and then it just shows a black square.

Thank you so much! it seems a step in the right direction even if it is not working for me yet.

Comment: btw, I am running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS and kernel 5.17.15-76051715-generic.

Comment: thanks! i fixed my Dell Precision 5470 too with this. cheese doesn't work but on MS teams it does

Comment: To get Cheese working, after installing the driver you can run the Cheese by the following command in terminal:
`sudo cheese -d "Intel MIPI Camera"`

Source: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-nz/000202122/webcam-function-does-not-work-in-linux-ubuntu-22-04-cheese-application

Answer (score 4):

On my freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my *Dell XPS Plus 9320* the trick was to simply select `Using HAL library for MIPI camera through Intel IPU6 from libcamhal-ipu6epO (open source)` in the **Additional Drivers** tab in "Software & Updates", applying the changes and then rebooting the computer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Full solution that finally worked for me, from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-ivsc-generic-hwe-22.04
$ sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried a whole bunch of fixes and this one worked, the 2nd line of extra modules being what I needed.  XPS 9315 with integrated webcam.

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: This worked flawlessly with Ubuntu 22.04.3 on my Dell Precision 5680.

Comment: somehow `linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04` motivated my system to do a kernel upgrade, which failed (cryptsetup was unable to detect disk for decryption and boot). So check upfront with `uname -r` if your current kernel version is at least as great as listed by `linux-modules-ipu6-KERNEL-VERSION` (dependency of the package in the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I just got my hands on the laptop, and with Dell being a pain in the butt about issuing the ISO to everyone, as long as you have Ubuntu 22.04 running, you can download the source from Github, compile and run. If you follow the rabbit hole, there are some deb packages somewhere, but you can always copy the firmware blobs, and make the dkms modules and it should work. Right now I am trying to get everything to compile for Fedora.

https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers

Comment: Did you ever sort this out on Fedora?  I just got this laptop, and hoped to avoid duplicating the effort of others.

Comment: With newer kernels, it is almost impossible to get anything to compile right, even with full source code. It looks for VSC code in older kernels, which is no longer present since it uses VIDEODEV instead of the V4Loopback stuff. Initially, I could get it to turn on, but it was like 4 FPS, I ran a DNF update, got a newer kernel, and it refused to compile. I had found an older Ubuntu 20.04 ISO for the machine, and it works, but it was way too outdated to be worth wild for me, and upgrading to 22.04 borks everything again.

Comment: There are a few detailed Arch Linux forum threads which have progressed far past this point, so I suspect its definitely possible.  But that doesn't help me with Fedora, as their build failures are not the same as mine, despite using relatively similar kernel versions.

Comment: Do you have any links? If I can get the one module to build out, I can either create a DKMS for it or hopefully build out an RPM that will work. The one I saw so far was someone in the same position that I had left it, somewhat working using V4loopback and like 4 FPS, and it wouldn't show up in Teams or Zoom due to the /dev/video interface not being used.

Comment: this is the best thread that I've found https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277462

Answer (score 1):

toomas's answer above initially worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0
```

But stopped working when I upgraded to 22.04.
After trying to use my phone with obs virtual camera + obs droid cam, I encountered this (READ THE SECURE BOOT PROMPTS CAREFULLY IF YOU TRY THIS):

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

[original post about reinstalling v4loopback](https://askubuntu.com/a/1356887)

So that didn't get my obs virtual cam to work, but my intel mipi camera is now working.

Comment: Nice one! I just made it work after reinstalling `v4l2loopback-dkms` on my Pop-OS 22.04 (using kernel 6.0). Thank you a lot! I'll try the same on my arch machine

Answer (score 1):

after several tries, i've finally discovered what result in a working webcam:

1. with secure boot enabled, formatted with 22.04.2 (this is not needed, just registering what led me to a working webcam). 22.04.01 was considered insecure by secure boot functionality (i only manage to make my webcam work when using secure boot enabled)
2. when formatting, turn on third party drivers, add a password for MOK and use it
3. follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424563/411689)
4. switch to 'do not use the device' (on both options) and back for 'using ... for ... (open source) (apply changes both times and restart when needed)
   [image: List item]
5. after a restart you should be able to `sudo cheese -d "Intel MIPI Camera"`. now microsoft teams and discord should also work
6. for firefox, do [this](https://github.com/stefanpartheym/archlinux-ipu6-webcam/issues/1#issuecomment-1370005030)

Comment: After several tries, this solution was the only one that worked for me. I had to choose "Do not use the device" for both options in the list: Intel IPU6 and oem-somerville.

After that I had to restart

Enable first the oem-sommerville -> restarted
Enable the Intel MIPI -> Restarted

Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic

Answer (score 1):

@toomas answer works for me, which in short involves following the instructions here
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell#Known_generic_issues

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6
$ sudo apt install libcamhal-ipu6ep0
$ sudo reboot
```

This did however create new issues. After rebooting I had very bad screen flicker. I found this could be fixed by adding
`i915.enable_psr=0 nomodeset`
to boot parameters in the grub configuration as described here
[Screen flicker after fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404771/screen-flicker-after-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem using [@toomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/1610085/toomas)' answer. I add that in Webcamoid I had to select "Intel MIPI Camera" as a source. After this it worked and it also started working in Cheese.

Comment: If you are going to use info from another answer great you gave credit but what if later that other answer is gone? Better to have included the other answer in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this issue we also had to use the same kernel that is installed in the Ubuntu 22.04 provided by Dell in the XPS Plus 9320 13th Gen i7. The current Kernel is **6.0.0-1020-oem**.

To install this kernel follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-add-repository deb http://oem.archive.canonical.com/ jammy jiayi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04b
sudo sudo apt full-upgrade
```

After the kernel is installed, reboot the system. You might have to change Grub to select this Kernel.

Also, make sure that the **oem-somerville-tentacool-meta** and **libcamhal-ipu6ep0** are installed and enabled in Additional Drivers.

After that, the camera is working in browser apps like Google meet.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell xps plus with ubuntu 22.04, as Schmoove did I selected `Using HAL library for MIPI camera through Intel IPU6 from libcamhal-ipu6epO` and the webcam works with meet, teams but not with cheese.
So I think the problem is in some settings of cheese.

Comment: not an answer exactly

Answer (score 0):

In my case (new Dell XPS Plus 9320 with Lubuntu 22.04) Additional Drivers showed the possibility of using "Using HAL library for MIPI camera through Intel IPU6 from libcamhal-ipu6epO" but I could not select it. I tried manually through the sudo ubuntu-drivers list / sudo ubuntu-drivers install procedure but still did not work. At the end, I had simply to install the corresponding .deb package

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on XPS 9315 after firmware upgrade on Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried [@Tony Liu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424563/657302) without success but then I solved the issue thank to this [thread](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/fr-fr/000203830/webcam-is-not-detected-on-xps-13-plus-9320-laptops-running-ubuntu-22-04?lang=en), proposing the following command lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta
sudo apt install oem-somerville-tentacool-meta
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo systemctl poweroff # this will shut down the computer
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend everybody read this documentation https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Dell#Known_generic_issues (search for `IPU6`).

These drivers are out-of-tree, more on this [here](https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers/issues/22)

At the time of this writing, the only certified platform is 20.04 (the packages with Pokemon names, like `oem-somerville-mewtwo-meta` etc).

For 22.04, the only option the doc suggests is to install from the **development** repository `ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta`. Be aware this is not a certified or stable repository so updates can make the camera stop working (I got bitten by this). I suggest you pin/hold the package to avoid issues later.

Initially what worked for me was just `libcamhal-ipu6ep0` but then an update broke it and now `libcamhal0` is enough. I then hold it (to prevent updates) with `sudo apt-mark hold libcamhal0`

Answer (score 0):

I follow several steps described ahead, but my webcam only works after some Intel drivers installation.

The steps are: 2.1.2 and 2.1.3, available at: `[https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/client/overview.html][1]`

Regards,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).