# ThinkPad X1 Carbon gen 10 webcam driver IPU6 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, intel, thinkpad, webcam

i have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 10th gen. It came with Ubuntu 20.04 preinstalled and the webcam (IPU6 Intel) worked fine, I think because an additional driver was installed by default, but when I upgraded and installed Ubuntu 22.04 the webcam doesn't work anymore. Does anyone have the same problem?

Cheese error:

[image: cheese error]

Answer (score 4):

I'm in the same boat and have done a bunch of research on the issue. There's no official fix today but things do look promising.

A description of the general issue:

- https://www.tomshardware.com/news/alder-lake-laptop-wonky-webcam-support

A possible, unconfirmed fix:

- https://github.com/intel/ipu6-camera-hal

And Lenovo's updates on their progress for an official fix:

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Fedora/Fedora-on-X1-Carbon-Gen-10/m-p/5135869

Post back here if you get it fixed and I'll do the same.

Comment: I have the same issue with Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 10, Kubuntu 22.04.
Tried installing from source and also this

https://askubuntu.com/a/1417193

Now the cam is detected by chrome as "Virtual Camera", but instead of image shows some stipes like No Signal image.

As of time writing, this state led to OOM and v4l2-relayd was killed thus reverting me to "No camera found" state.

Comment: Also now I am experiencing this issue https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg492634.html
EDIT: Problematic `v4l2-relayd` comes from `libcamhal-ipu6ep0` from here `ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6`
So if there are any news about the bugs resolution/workarounds for cameras would be glad to hear

Comment: Is there any update on this? I just bought a new X1 and I am really frustrated that the camera does not work

Comment: I finally got it working: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1461734/mipi-webcam-with-thinkpad-x1-gen10-not-working-with-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1&lq=1