# Dell xps plus 9320 ubuntu 22.04 camera not working

Tags: dell, webcam, camera

I have a new dell xps plus 9320 and I installed Ubuntu 22.04.
Everything works great, except the camera that is not working.
The computer detect the camera but when I am trying to use it (for example with zoom) it shows a black screen.

Do I need to install a specific driver for the camera or something else?

I would appreciate if you can help me solve the problem.

Comment: Did you set correct permissions on the camera?

Comment: this is the permissions for /dev/video0: crw-rw----+  1 root  video

Comment: Are you a member of group "video"?

Comment: yes I am a member

Comment: I also tried this solution but it didn’t work- https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-il/000203830/webcam-is-not-detected-on-xps-13-plus-9320-laptops-running-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Check this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414767/dell-xps-plus-9320-webcam-not-detected-in-ubuntu-22-04/1459719#1459719