# OBS Studio virtual camera doesn't work on virtual machine (v4l2loopback-dkms)

Tags: kernel, virtualization, webcam, secure-boot, obs-studio

I am currently trying to set up the [virtual camera in OBS Studio](https://jonathanbossenger.com/2020/12/17/obs-studio-linux-virtual-camera/) on my Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine (DigitalOcean droplet) by installing the `v4l2loopback-dkms` module. However, although the virtual camera button is appearing in the OBS software, clicking it does nothing, as described in this [Stack Overflow question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332772/obs-studio-virtual-camera-wont-work). Here is a log of what occurs when I install the `v4l2loopback` module:

```
ramy@opal-cafe:~$ sudo apt -y install v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed: [ABRIDGED]
Suggested packages: [ABRIDGED]
The following NEW packages will be installed: [ABRIDGED]
0 upgraded, 38 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
Need to get 37.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 173 MB of additional disk space will be used [ABRIDGED]
Fetched 37.6 MB in 1s (33.1 MB/s)               
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
[ABRIDGED]
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up v4l2loopback-dkms (0.12.3-1ubuntu0.4) ...
Loading new v4l2loopback-0.12.3 DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-107-generic
Building initial module for 5.4.0-107-generic
Can't load /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/.rnd into RNG
139665634772288:error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file: ../crypto/rand/randfile.c:98:Filename=/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/.rnd
Generating a RSA private key
............................................................+++++
...............................+++++
writing new private key to '/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv'
-----
EFI variables are not supported on this system
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars not found, aborting.
Done.

v4l2loopback.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-107-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
```

After uninstalling and reinstalling both the `v4l2loopback` module and OBS Studio a few times in different ways to no avail, as well as using `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`, I tried the suggestion to disable secure boot via [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114867/operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-modprobe-xpad/1198351#1198351). However, when I try to check for the secure boot state using `mokutil --sb-state`, I encounter this error:

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
```

Other suggested methods of disabling Secure Boot were to disable it from BIOS, but I’m not sure how to access that, this being a virtual machine (I’m using xrdp with Gnome desktop to get a GUI). If anyone has any suggestions on what I can do next, please let me know - I’m pretty new to Ubuntu and am going in blind.

**Adding a follow-up here:** when I run `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`, I get this error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```