# WiFi adapter not found Realtek 10ec:8852 on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, 21.04, adapter

I have a Ubuntu 21.04 fresh install but my Wifi is not working. It states: "Wi-Fi adapter not found". The card is an Intel wifi 6 AX200.
When writing lshw -C network it shoes network unclaimed
And it says nothing about wifi 6 ax 200, it says something about realtek.
Ubuntu 21.04 should be compatible since its kernel is >5.1 as required by this wifi card.
Any help will be greatly appreciated...
D

Edit after chili555's comment:
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e1]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Sandisk Corp WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD [15b7:5006]
```

In the laptop specs it says it should have an Intel Wifi6 AX200!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi! Nothing appears, just asks for my password and nothing else...

Comment: How can I check if I have the necessary firmware? I've cd into lib/firmware/ and then ls but all the iwlwifi files seem to have different names to the one I need (iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz as per Intel webpage)?

Comment: I am wondering if you do not actually have an Intel. Please edit your question to show the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` I love a mystery!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, if you wish, you could return the laptop and request that you instead receive a replacement equipped with the captioned Intel AX200. As well, you could easily install the correct driver for your Realtek device.

With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo cp  rtw8852a_fw.bin  /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Your wireless should now be working.

**EDIT**: From time to time, when security flaws are corrected, when bugs are fixed or when new features are added, Update Manager will offer updates that include ‘Complete Linux Image’, that is, a newer kernel version than that installed today. After the update is installed, you will be prompted to restart to complete the update. After you restart, your wireless will no longer be working. To restore the wireless, open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/rtw89
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Please retain the rtw89 file and these instructions for that time.

At some future time, the rtw89 suite of drivers will be included in the latest kernels and this process will no longer be required. We haven’t yet any idea when that may occur.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to contact them and see what solution they provide. Thank you so much for your time! <3

Comment: Hi! I come with an update: I just followed your instructions to install the Realtek driver and voilâ, I have Wi-Fi!
I don't really understand how to update when kernel changes? Could you explain that a bit more? I don't understand what you mean by retaining the rtw89 file. Should I do the cd~/rtw89 etc commands before updating? I'm sorry, I'm quite new to this...

Comment: No worries; all of us were new users at one time, even me! Please see my edit in a few moments. Also, if my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you edit your question to change the title to something like: *WiFi adapter not found Realtek 10ec:8852* again, to help the searchers. A great value of the site is to not only to help you but also to help many others with the same issue who find the answer that helped you.

Comment: @chili555 If you have the time, can you see if you can help with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04?noredirect=1#1352653? Thanks.

Comment: @chili555, I've been using ethernet for a month now and when I went to connect to Wi-Fi again, it didn't work. It showed: "Wi-Fi Adapter not found" should I follow the instructions you gave me for updates? I mean this one:
cd ~/rtw89
git pull
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw89pci

Comment: @user7292119 Yes, exactly! Please proceed.

Comment: @chili555
Hello agaim, for some reason, it loses the Wi-Fi adapters quite frequently and when I tried to follow the instructions for the updates, it gave me the following error:
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Exec format error
The Wi-Fi will not connect...
Thanks for your time

Comment: Please run the process again but stop after 'make' and show us the result. Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 sorry for not responding, I've been super busy...Just tried to do it again (put the commands for updating) today and it suddenly worked...do you know why this could be?

Comment: @user7292119 I haven't any idea without examining the logs. If it's working, it's all good.

Comment: if you change kernel version and error keeps, than delete `rm -rf /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89 ./rtw89` will help to start with

Comment: @chili555 unfortunately, I don't have the logs from when it didn't work...if it happens again (let's hope not) I'll add them. Thank you for your help <3

Answer (score 3):

When running "sudo modprobe rtw89pci" above, you may run into 'operation not permitted' problems.

```
sudo modprobe rtw89pci   - 'operation not permitted'
```

This is because of SecureBoot enabled in your OS. You can follow this link to [check and disable SecureBoot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114867/operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-modprobe-xpad).

```
sudo apt-get install mokutil
mokutil --sb-state
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Then you need to reboot and follow instructions to disable mok secureboot.

After reboot, run "sudo modprobe rtw89pci" again. It should work.

Good luck!

Comment: FYI. The wifi disappeared again overnight. I tried below and the wifi just came back.

     cd ~/rtw89;
     sudo make install;
     sudo modprobe rtw89pci;

Note that don't try to run 'make' as you don't have internet access. Since I have finished 'Make' last time, I just did 'make install'

Comment: I always run those commands when connected to ethernet so for me it's not a problem!

Answer (score 1):

When ubuntu gets updated, wifi driver may stop working. When you try install the driver again you may get the following error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Exec format error

This happens because you are trying to install the previously compiled files on the new kernel. The solution is to compile the files again.
One possible way to do this is to

```
cd rtw99
rm *.o # removes previous .o files
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo cp  rtw8852a_fw.bin  /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't even update ubuntu...For some reason today it worked on its own, just had to repeat @chili555 commands from the previous accepted answer