# Ubuntu 20.04: No Wi-Fi adapter found

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, lenovo

I just got a new PC, a Lenovo Ideapad 5 Pro, and I put Ubuntu 20.04 on it right out of the box. However, when I go to connect to the internet it says that there was no Wi-Fi adapter found. I also discovered that the laptop does not have an ethernet port, so I can't even connect through a wired connection.

I believe the issue is a driver issue, I'm having trouble finding a suitable driver, but I do have a Wi-Fi adapter which I also need to install a driver for (Linksys WUSB6300) and so I found a driver that should work for that, [here](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux/), which hopefully will get me on the internet and then I can fix the issue with the built in wireless card.

However this driver requires me to use the `make` command, which is not installed. I thought I could transfer in the .deb file for `make` from a different computer and install it on Ubuntu, but it has dependencies, so I downloaded those files, but those files have their own dependencies and so on, which is quite frustrating, and I'm hesitant to follow that path because I don't know how deep the rabbit hole goes, so to speak.

I'm really not sure what to do since there's no way to connect to the internet with the laptop that has the issue, and all the solutions I've found require an internet connection to fix the problem. I was thinking of going to buy a USB to ethernet adapter to try and get a connection, but I'm not sure if that would also require a driver to work, which I won't be able to install. Does anyone have a suggestion for a solution to this problem? If so any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` result:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
```

Comment: You can always connect your phone to USB ;-)

Comment: What driver are you trying to build? Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: "Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]" The method to install the driver is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04/1352314#1352314 As @Pilot6 correctly suggests, you may be able to tether your phone to get an internet connection. Also, almost every commonly available USB-to-ethernet adapter works with drivers built-in to Ubuntu. Finally, if you have unlimited patience, we can propose a method to install the prerequisites using the USB drive from which you installed Ubuntu. It is long and painful but works.

Comment: @chili555 
I'm getting the following error when I run
`sudo modprobe rtw89pci`
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtw89pci': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Please disable Secure Boot in the BIOS/EFI and try again.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you so much! That worked, I can use my wifi now.