# Realtek 10ec:8852 pci adapter not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek

I am brand new to Linux and am having trouble with my PCI Wi-Fi adapter and the drivers associated with it. I recently downloaded the 21.04 version of Ubuntu and made the switch from Windows. Once it installed, my existing PCI card that came with the laptop stopped working (Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM is the device name when I run `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`).

When I searched for answers and solutions I found
[WiFi adapter not found Realtek 10ec:8852 on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04)
and followed along to no avail or internet. I tried other available forums and solutions (too many to mention here) downloading different drivers and git repos. Now I am afraid I am doing more harm than good. Like I said, I am brand new to the Linux world so be gentle. Below are a few screen captures of a couple of useful commands from the terminal that might give everyone more information.

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
usb0    ethernet  connected    Wired connection 2 
enp2s0  ethernet  unavailable  --                 
lo      loopback  unmanaged    --                 
demian@demianPC:~/rtw89$
```

```
$ sudo modprobe rtw89pci
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtw89pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.14.9-051409-generic
demian@demianPC:~$
```

```
$ lspci
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852
// There was other but didn't seem necessary
```

How can I get my Wi-Fi working?

Comment: I am having similar issues on Pop! OS. I think most of the drivers are present, in particular there is a driver rtw88_88XXpci that you can make work, and a few others, if you do `ls -R | grep rtw` or `ls -R | grep rtl` in `/lib` or `/lib/modules` you can find them, I tried starting them but I dont know where to go from there.