# Ubuntu 20.04 on T14 gen 1 amd the wifi does not work

Tags: 20.04

I have recently purchased a Lenovo ThinkPad T14 (Gen 1) notebook and, when I installed ubuntu 20.04, the wifi stopped working. I have updated all of the drivers, but the wireless card does not work.

This is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852] Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01) Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:5082]
```

How can I use WiFi on this notebook?

Comment: Let's gather some details about your wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:5082]


This is the network driver information for my thinkpad T14 gen 1 laptop

Comment: You need to install the rtw89 driver for your 10ec:8852 wireless. Please see the duplicate for the procedure. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi adapter not found Realtek 10ec:8852 on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04)

Answer (score 0):

For someone who installing Ubuntu on their T14 gen 1 AMD and get the same error, and can find `/usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/` when trying ubuntu live version. Simply try enabling the module:
`sudo modprobe rtw89pci`