# Wired connection fails to connect every time and turns itself off on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have a dual booted system and the connection works fine on windows so it's definitely not a problem with the cable or the port. Turning it on gives the "Wired connecting" message for a while before it turns itself off.

The wifi is working fine.

```
sudo lshw -class network

 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: 38:f3:ab:e7:d4:05
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:39 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:fd604000-fd604fff memory:fd600000-fd603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:4c:a1:cf:ef:87
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_pci driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.42.0.206 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:74 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd500000-fd5fffff
```

I used to experience problems with my wifi when I first installed ubuntu on this laptop a few months ago due to my network adapter but [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04) helped me fix it.

Comment: how do you receive your ethernet? have you access to the router?

Comment: I do not have access to a router. The university just provides lan ports. I do not think it is an issue with the ports though since they work fine when I boot into windows.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: in Windows open cmd and run `ipconfig/release &amp; net stop dhcp`, Win should show that you have no internet, reboot to Ubuntu and see if it gets ip address

Comment: @waltinator I don't understand what exactly to read. The page is huge.

Comment: @andra I raan the command on windows and switched to Ubuntu and the problem persists

Comment: do you have experience with Wireshark or other packet analyzing tool? You could run Wireshark and see Ubuntu dhcp requests and what exactly it receives back.

Comment: concerning dhcp release in Win: did you really see that Windows is without internet? Because after ip release, if dhcp is not stopped fast enough, Win receives a new address and it's the same situation.