# Installing wifi drivers for Ubuntu (Asus)

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, asus

Note - I'm not really experienced with linux so sorry if I get anything wrong.

I've set up my computer to dual boot, I have windows 10 installed on an SSD and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a HDD (I've installed it with a pendrive). When I booted into Ubuntu I went to settings -> Wi-Fi to try to enable the Wi-Fi but got a message saying "No Wi-Fi adapter found", so I went to [ASUS's website](https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-b650m-a-wifi/helpdesk_download/?model2Name=PRIME-B650M-A-WIFI) to get the necessary drivers (I'm using the Wi-Fi card provided by my motherboard) but noticed that there's are no drivers avaible for "Other OS".

[image]

So now I'm wondering how do I go on about installing the necessary drivers to be able to use Wi-Fi?

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop, I've followed step 2 on the link you posted and then went to help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/… (as the guide says), but I'm "failing" at step 3.2 (run the command sudo iwconfig), the output says "no wireless extensions", any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: It's helpful if you're specific with details; you mention Ubuntu 22.04 LTS but not if Desktop or Server (they have different kernel defaults).  Either way *drivers* for Linux are actually kernel modules (*thus kernel stack matters*!) and are built for a chipset (not make/model of board) so I'd suggest following the appropriate documentation for your *unstated* 22.04 product, eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Devices

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'm using Ubuntu Desktop, I've followed step 2 on the link you posted and then went to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers (as the guide says), but I'm "failing" at step 3.2 (run the command `sudo iwconfig`), the output says "no wireless extensions", any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: This isn't a forum, but a Q&A site.  Please add additional details to your question (eg. Desktop should be added to your question, plus any pastes that may reveal detail useful information such as brand/model of chips to your question), not reply via comments which are intended for readers to the OP/Original Poster & get deleted once addressed in the question itself.  eg. detail needed is what's on your motherboard, eg. *Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200* or other, as chips can vary if boards sell well & remain in production for >3 months.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the users who tried to help me and apologies for not providing enough details, I was using my phone (because I had Ubuntu on my computer with no internet access) so copy-pasting the output of certain commands wasn't gonna be easy, here's how I ended up fixing the issue.

1. Connected an ethernet cable to my computer, Ubuntu recognized it immediately so I didn't have to do anything else to get access to the internet.
2. Installed build-essential (`sudo apt install build-essential`).
3. Installed git (`sudo apt install git`).
4. Run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
5. Found out my wi-fi chispet (more info [here](https://fostips.com/realtek-wifi-drivers-ubuntu-linux-mint/#rb-How-to-Tell-Which-Wi-Fi-Chipset-you-have)).

   1. Installled `hardinfo` (System Profiler and Benchmark) from Ubuntu Software.
   2. Found my network card under Devices -> PCI and got the chipset name from there.
6. Followed the steps detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1352314/1668759) (because the OP of that post was also looking to install drivers for the same chipset as I was, don't go there blindly).

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89
sudo cp  rtw8852a_fw.bin  /usr/lib/firmware/rtw89/
sudo modprobe rtw89pci
```