# Asus Prime B660 motherboard WiFi not working

Tags: asus

How do I get the Motherboard Wifi Working on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS  It is enabled in the bios but nowhere in settings for WiFi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing wifi drivers for Ubuntu (Asus)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1452546/installing-wifi-drivers-for-ubuntu-asus)

Comment: Neither of the above work for me. terminal is not seeing Any wireless controller only Ethernet.

Comment: The question seems unanswerable with the limited information provided. You have been provided a link detailing the information we need to provide a useful answer.