# Wifi adapter not found 17aa:e0bc on Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, mediatek

I have a lenovo ideapad with ubuntu 22.04.2 on it. Few days ago I started experiencing some intermittent issues on the wifi connection (*WiFi adapter not found*), therefore I just decided to reinstall the OS but not much has changed, sometimes the wifi is just not working.

Refering to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04?newreg=cf48bb137a554042aa2daac046b7dd9a) I ran *lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3* on terminal and this is what I get:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:e0bc]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
```

To make these go away I either sometimes turn off/on wifi, or restart the computer many times when the latter doesn't help.

To be more specific the issues can be: disconnecting automatically from wifi, being connected to wifi but not to the internet, unable to connect to wifi (I try to connect and this phase is neverending).

Thanks for your help!

## UPDATES

- I applied the solution [here](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/from-5-19-11-to-5-19-14-wireless-doesnt-work-mediatek-mt7921-driver/68367/14) specific for Mediatek
- I tried disabling powersave on wifi module
- I tried moving back to Ubuntu 20.04

Nevertheless nothing is different.

As a new "symptom" I also got this message:

[image]

Comment: Faced a similar problem on an ASUSTeK VivoBook M1403QA laptop. And found topic https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/from-5-19-11-to-5-19-14-wireless-doesnt-work-mediatek-mt7921-driver/68367/14. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I already had the mediatek folder in my system (differently from the linked question) but it was slightly different. Now I have installed the one downloaded from your link and (at least) the wifi still works. So I'll see now if the intermittent issues disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Most often this happens due to the enabled power saving mode (powersave) for the Wi-Fi adapter.

To disable powersave mode, run in the console:

iwconfig wlan0 power off

Where wlan0 is the name of the adapter.  You can find out the name of the adapter using the ifconfig command.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Since the issues I faced were intermittent I cannot say if this specific solution actually will solve the problem. Until either they come back or some time has past and the issues have disappeared.
In the meantime I applied your suggestion though. Moreover, as a sidenote, I saw that `iwconfig wlan0 power off` had to be repeated every time I turned the system on, so I actually used `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to modify the corresponding variable from 3 to 2 to make the change permanent at every boot.