# WiFi adapter not found Realtek 10ec:8852 on Ubuntu 21.04 - solution

Tags: 20.04, wireless, iwlwifi, adapter

I don't have enough reputation points to either add an answer or even a comment to the question "[WiFi adapter not found Realtek 10ec:8852 on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04)", so I am adding it how I fixed this issue, as a question. Hope this helps anyone.

To be clear, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new HP laptop and it was not detecting the wifi device.

The previous answers probably worked well, but it required you to have a specific kernel version. Knowing this I installed several kernel versions using the method [described here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/) and besides installing the older kernel versions, I also installed the newest kernel (6.4). Rebooted the laptop and wireless simply started working.

One last thing that I did was to change GRUB to has as default starting twith that kernel, that I did by using the [Grub customizer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) (see top answer on that link).