# Wifi Problem on Ubuntu 20.04 -

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I have installed the Ubuntu 20.04 to my old laptop Lenovo G580.

Since then I could connect internet via ethernet but there is no sign or driver for Wifi. So, I tried a couple of solution, installing kernel etc. But there is still the problem.

The driver is Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

Appreciate any help, I try every solution find in websites....

Comment: unfortunately... it did not work. I tried again but there is no wifi.

Comment: Actually, I try to solve this problem almost for a week by today including reinstalling ubuntu again and again. So when i saw a solution I can remember whether I tried or not... But thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a shell terminal window (you may press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> or right-click a free area of your Desktop and then select `Open Terminal`, among other ways to do it) and then run the commands below.

1. Install the Linux firmware support package and also the Broadcom support packages for your device (the two `broadcom-*` packages below add support for BCM43142):

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-firmware broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-dkms -y --reinstall
   ```
2. Unload conflicting Broadcom modules (i.e. kernel device drivers for other/conflicting Broadcom devices):

   ```
   modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
   ```
3. Load the wifi module for your Broadcom device:

   ```
   sudo modprobe wl
   ```
4. Reboot:

   ```
   reboot
   ```

PS: if step #2 fails, try running step #3 before step #2 (i.e. first load the `wl` module and only then attempt to unload the conflicting modules). If step #3 fails aswell or for any reason your wifi still doesn't work, [disable Secure Boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198351/389062) and then try the above steps again.

Comment: after second step there is an error message:

'modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:799 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'b43': Operation not permitted
modprobe: FATAL: Module ssb is in use.'

is that normal?

Comment: @leyla In such case, execute step #1, ignore (don't execute) step #2 and then execute steps #3 and #4. If your wifi works, the modules aren't conflicting. If however the modules conflict and you therefore can't use wifi, you likely need to disabe Secure Boot and then execute the 4 steps above again, because Secure Boot is likely preventing unloading the conflicting module. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198351/389062).

Comment: I disabled the secure boot and repeated all steps then it worked!

thank you so much!

Comment: @leyla Awesome. You're welcome. Glad to help.  :)