# How can i stop battery charging on my MSI laptop at 50%?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, msi

MSI laptops users in windows can easily set a limit for battery charging in DragonCenter:

[image]

So it allows users to improve battery lifetime.
But whats about Linux and ubuntu?

Thinkpad users also can use this solution: [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34452/1067947)

HP users can modify this value from BIOS: [Configuring battery charging limit to desired value (70-80%) on HP laptop](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Gaming-Notebooks/Configuring-battery-charging-limit-to-desired-value-70-80-on/td-p/6940972)

But what about MSI laptops (which windows users can modify this value from DragonCenter app)?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this as well, I don't have an answer so I'm writing a comment instead.
You might find some luck checking out these sources: TLP support based on a Linux Kernel 4.17 change - https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/321 also this project might be helpful however I haven't checked the code or tested if it works yet: https://github.com/YoyPa/isw

Comment: isw does include battery limiting, and considering it's meant as a drop-in replacement to Dragon Center, it should work. Can't verify that though, because my battery is horrible and the OS cannot measure the charge correctly, but should still work on a battery that's less garbage. I'm not sure if it takes percentages relative to the max capacity or the current capacity, though. I'd assume current, but I keep hopping >90% even though it's limited. Again, might just be down to the charge being hard to measure with my old and heavily (ab)used battery, but /shrug

Answer (score 1):

Note : This is not the complete answer to your question.

If you have dual boot, you can try setting it up in windows and it carries over to Ubuntu 22.04. In my case, I have a limit of 80% set in windows (through MSI Center) which carries over to Ubuntu 22.04. I am quite surprised that it works this way since I don't know of any way to reset it to charge to full capacity through Ubuntu itself now.

Model of my laptop : MSI Modern 15 B7M

Answer (score 0):

Have a look around in your BIOS/UEFI settings, there should be an option about battery health management for your laptop. I own an HP laptop and my option is called `adaptive battery`, perhaps there is something similar for yours. Keep in mind that every BIOS/UEFI is different, so please do look at your manufacturer's laptop documentations for better answers.