# Lenovo Ideapad 3 battery charging limit (for beginners)

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, ideapad, charging

I have a new laptop IdeaPad 3 (15ARH05) and Ubuntu 21.04, and I want to preserve the battery in good condition by preventing *non stop charging*.
I've searched the other questions and I couldn't find a solution.

My intention is to find a solution and also, to make this solution available for  beginners (newcomers from windows), so I would need step by step guidance, with feedback from Terminal.

- if I try Tp smapi I get this  ERROR: could not insert 'tp_smapi': No such device
  ([How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)) The solution given it referes to Lenovo thinkpad, i have Lenovo ideapad, maybe is because of this, I don't know.
- if I unzip this extension https://gitlab.com/karim.samir.lotfy/charging-mode-gnome-shell-extention, I don't know how to install it (gnome extension on chrome is installed)
  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode/

Maybe we could start with this extension, and help me install it, to see if is working, then any other way to fix this issue.
Thank you!

Comment: Anyone can help me with this extension, or other solution?

Comment: Anyone can help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4331/ideapad-mode/ or https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging/.

You may also simply type `sudo echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode` in the terminal.